# I want to get the username of the teacher when i redirect to the message page

Tags: php, codeigniter

kindly help me i am stuck on this issue.
when a student click on "Ask Question" button then the student will redirect to the message page but i want that when the student will redirect then the username of the specfic teacher will appears on the compose message script.

```
<?php  if($usertype == "Student") { ?>
<td data-title="<?=$this->lang->line('action')?>">
    <a href="<?=base_url("mark/view")?>"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-view" style="margin-bottom:10px" value="View Marks" ></a>
    <a href="<?=base_url("message/add")?>"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:0px" value="Ask Questions"></a>
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

the table of teacher with respect to the subjects are

```
<td data-title="<?=$this->lang->line('subject_teacher')?>">
    <?php echo $subject->teacher_name; ?>
</td>
```

kindly help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you realize you are not echoing values in the HTML quotes?

Comment: Butt sb can you dump ./ print_r ($subject) to see whether you are getting teacher name from your model or not

Answer (score 0):

I would use a cookie, personally. Like this:

```
setcookie("teacher", $teacher_name);
```

Then you can access the cookie like this:

```
$teacher = $_COOKIE["your cookie name"];
```

More information can be found here:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php